# hitTestObject detecting collision even when there is no collision and in another case its not registering

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hello guys i am doing my University Project on this small tamogachi game where i drag and drop stuff on the char and his health or money wtv changes according to it and we had to do it with multiple classes so eveything is good except the hitTestObject if not registering properly through different classes.

Here is my code and all my project files link is also attached below please help:

Link for project files: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B07PZ7vQgjsteWhVMnItczd2YUE&usp=sharing

Main Class:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.Timer;


    public class Main extends MovieClip {





        public var addStuff:AddStuff = new AddStuff;
        public var hmClass:HealthMoney = new HealthMoney;

        public function Main() {

            addChild(addStuff.bg);


            addStuff.batMan.x = 700;
            addStuff.batMan.y = 600;
            addChild(addStuff.batMan);

            addChild(addStuff.box);
            addStuff.box.x = 1050;
            addStuff.box.y = 500;

            addChild(addStuff.batHealth);
            addStuff.batHealth.x = 890;
            addStuff.batHealth.y = 430;

            addChild(addStuff.dollar);
            addStuff.dollar.x = 890;
            addStuff.dollar.y = 570;

            addChild(addStuff.men);
            addStuff.men.x = 800;
            addStuff.men.y = 900;

            addChild(addStuff.batBurger);
            addStuff.batBurger.x = 400;
            addStuff.batBurger.y = 900;

            addChild(addStuff.batDrink);
            addStuff.batDrink.x = 600;
            addStuff.batDrink.y = 900;

            addChild(addStuff.batMoney);
            addStuff.batMoney.x = 850;
            addStuff.batMoney.y = 940;

            AddHealth();
            AddMoney();


            }

        public function AddHealth(){

            hmClass.HealthTimer();
            addChild(hmClass.myHealthText);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Kill);
            function Kill(e:Event){

                if(hmClass.health <= 0){

                    hmClass.batLifeTimer.stop();
                    addStuff.batMan.rotation -= 1;
                    if(addStuff.batMan.rotation <= -80){

                        addStuff.batMan.alpha = -5;

                        }


                    }

                }


        }

        public function AddMoney(){

                addChild(hmClass.myMoneyText);
                hmClass.Money();



                }










    }

}
```

AddStuff Class:

```
package  {


    public class AddStuff{

        public var bg:BG = new BG();
        public var batHealth:BatHealth = new BatHealth();
        public var batMan:BatMan = new BatMan();
        public var batBurger:BatBurger = new BatBurger();
        public var batDrink:BatDrink = new BatDrink();
        public var batMoney:BatMoney = new BatMoney();
        public var men:Men = new Men();
        public var box:Box = new Box();
        public var dollar:Dollar = new Dollar();

        public function AddStuff() {



        }



    }

}
```

HealthMoney Class:

```
package  {
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class HealthMoney extends MovieClip{

        public var health:int = 100;
        public var money:int = 100;
        public var batLifeTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
        public var myHealthText:TextField = new TextField();
        public var myHealthTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        public var myMoneyText:TextField = new TextField();
        public var myMoneyTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        public var addStuffClass:AddStuff = new AddStuff;
        public var addStuff1:AddStuff = new AddStuff;
        public function HealthMoney() {
            // constructor code

        }

        public function HealthTimer(){


            myHealthText.setTextFormat(myHealthTextFormat);
            myHealthTextFormat.size = 120;
            myHealthTextFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF;

            myHealthText.defaultTextFormat = myHealthTextFormat;
            //myHealthText.border = true;
            myHealthText.x = 970;
            myHealthText.y = 350;
            myHealthText.width = 200;
            myHealthText.height = 120;





            batLifeTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);

            function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void{

                health--;
                //trace(health);
                myHealthText.text = health.toString();
                }


            batLifeTimer.start();




            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, BatBurger);
            function BatBurger(e:Event):void{

                if(addStuff1.batMan.hitTestObject(addStuff1.batBurger)){

                    health++;
                    //trace("yo");

                    }

                }






            }


        public function Money():void{

            myMoneyText.setTextFormat(myMoneyTextFormat);
            myMoneyTextFormat.size = 120;
            myMoneyTextFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF;

            myMoneyText.defaultTextFormat = myMoneyTextFormat;
            myMoneyText.border = true;
            myMoneyText.x = 970;
            myMoneyText.y = 500;
            myMoneyText.width = 500;
            myMoneyText.height = 200;
            //addChild(myMoneyText);
            myMoneyText.text = money.toString();

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, AddMoney);

            function AddMoney(e:MouseEvent):void{

                if(addStuff1.batMoney.hitTestObject(addStuff1.batMan)){

                    myMoneyText.text = money.toString();
                    money = money + 100;
                    trace("hey");


                    }



                }



            }











    }
}
```

and the DraggableItem Class:

(this class is the base class of all the objects i want to drag)

```
package  {

    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class DraggableItem extends MovieClip{

        public function DraggableItem() {

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startmove);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopmove);

        }

        public function startmove(e:MouseEvent){

            this.startDrag();

            }
        public function stopmove(e:MouseEvent){

            this.stopDrag();

            }

    }

}
```

Comment: so, what is the problem ? I don't see hitTestObject into your project... where do you test collision?

Comment: the problem is that i made a hit test object which detects collison between the burger and batman, so when i drag and drop the burger on him his heath should increase by 10 but it keeps on increasing every frame and same with the money nothing happens when i drop money on him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Main class:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.display.Stage; 

public class Main extends MovieClip {




    public static var stageRef:Stage; 
    public var addStuff:AddStuff = new AddStuff;
    public var hmClass:HealthMoney;

    public function Main() {

        stageRef = stage;

        addChild(addStuff.bg);


        addStuff.batMan.x = 700;
        addStuff.batMan.y = 600;
        addChild(addStuff.batMan);

        addChild(addStuff.box);
        addStuff.box.x = 1050;
        addStuff.box.y = 500;

        addChild(addStuff.batHealth);
        addStuff.batHealth.x = 890;
        addStuff.batHealth.y = 430;

        addChild(addStuff.dollar);
        addStuff.dollar.x = 890;
        addStuff.dollar.y = 570;

        addChild(addStuff.men);
        addStuff.men.x = 800;
        addStuff.men.y = 900;

        addChild(addStuff.batBurger);
        addStuff.batBurger.x = 400;
        addStuff.batBurger.y = 900;

        addChild(addStuff.batDrink);
        addStuff.batDrink.x = 600;
        addStuff.batDrink.y = 900;

        addChild(addStuff.batMoney);
        addStuff.batMoney.x = 850;
        addStuff.batMoney.y = 940;

        hmClass = new HealthMoney(addStuff);

        AddHealth();
        AddMoney();


        }

    public function AddHealth(){

        hmClass.HealthTimer();
        addChild(hmClass.myHealthText);

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Kill);
        function Kill(e:Event){

            if(hmClass.health <= 0){

                hmClass.batLifeTimer.stop();
                addStuff.batMan.rotation -= 1;
                if(addStuff.batMan.rotation <= -80){

                    addStuff.batMan.alpha = -5;

                    }


                }

            }


    }

    public function AddMoney(){

            addChild(hmClass.myMoneyText);
            hmClass.Money();



            }










}

}
```

HealthMoney class:

```
package  {
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class HealthMoney extends MovieClip{

    public var health:int = 100;
    public var money:int = 100;
    public var batLifeTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
    public var myHealthText:TextField = new TextField();
    public var myHealthTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    public var myMoneyText:TextField = new TextField();
    public var myMoneyTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    public var addStuffClass:AddStuff = new AddStuff;
    public var addStuff1:AddStuff;

    public function HealthMoney(addStuff:AddStuff) {
        this.addStuff1 = addStuff;

    }

    public function HealthTimer(){


        myHealthText.setTextFormat(myHealthTextFormat);
        myHealthTextFormat.size = 120;
        myHealthTextFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF;

        myHealthText.defaultTextFormat = myHealthTextFormat;
        //myHealthText.border = true;
        myHealthText.x = 970;
        myHealthText.y = 350;
        myHealthText.width = 200;
        myHealthText.height = 120;





        batLifeTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);

        function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void{

            health--;
            //trace(health);
            myHealthText.text = health.toString();
            }


        batLifeTimer.start();




        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, BatBurger);
        function BatBurger(e:Event):void{

            if(addStuff1.batMan.hitTestObject(addStuff1.batBurger)){

                health++;
                //trace("yo");

                }

            }






        }


    public function Money():void{

        myMoneyText.setTextFormat(myMoneyTextFormat);
        myMoneyTextFormat.size = 120;
        myMoneyTextFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF;

        myMoneyText.defaultTextFormat = myMoneyTextFormat;
        myMoneyText.border = true;
        myMoneyText.x = 970;
        myMoneyText.y = 500;
        myMoneyText.width = 500;
        myMoneyText.height = 200;
        //addChild(myMoneyText);
        myMoneyText.text = money.toString();

        Main.stageRef.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, AddMoney);

        function AddMoney(e:MouseEvent):void{

            if(addStuff1.batMoney.hitTestObject(addStuff1.batMan)){

                myMoneyText.text = money.toString();
                money = money + 100;
                trace("hey");


                }



            }



        }











}
}
```

The line "public static var stageRef:Stage;" creates a static variable of the type Stage. Static variables are accessible from other classes without needing an instance of the class.

The line "stageRef = stage" basically sets the value of stageRef to stage. You access the stageRef by simply writing "Main.stageRef". You need a instance of the stage because of the line "Main.stageRef.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, AddMoney);" in the HealthMoney class. The mouse_up event will not work properly if you only write "addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, AddMoney);", since the focus is on the stage.

The line "hmClass = new HealthMoney(addStuff);" sends the instance of the AddStuff class to the HealthMoney constructor. You need to do that because if you write "addStuff1 = new AddStuff", you will create a new instance of AddStuff, and the new instance of AddStuff does not have the movieclips you added in the main class, which will make the hittestobject not triggering.

Comment: kinda makes sense but still this is the error i get
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at HealthMoney/HealthTimer()
 at Main/AddHealth()
 at Main()

and then the health and money just disappears

Comment: Does it say which line? Because I just tried it and it worked fine for me when I used the files...

Comment: nah it just shows this error. i copied the error and pasted it

Comment: Try to use the files from the link in your description, and then just copy the code I wrote to them and try it.

Comment: would be really helpfull if you could explain what changes you made and how they work. thanks alot again

Comment: No problem :). Added explanation the answer, excuse my English, it is not very good.